# Filemaker filter a relationship

Tags: filemaker, relationships

How do I filter a Filemaker relationship? The reason I'm asking:
having a main table with records imported from an excel file, sorted to date.
I have 12 tables (1 for each month) to be accessed separately.
The clumsy way would be to import the Excel sheet 12 times and delete the records not needed for the month-table.
How can I do this with relationships, like one can accomplish with a filtered portal?
I think it can be done with a global and a join table, but how exactly?

Comment: Your question is not clear. The only thing I can say for certain is that you should **not** have a separate table for each month.

Comment: As @michael.hor257k says, the records should be in one table, then make a number field to indicate the month number. If you want 12 separate relationships, then define a further 12 number calculation fields from 1 to 12 as constants and use them in 12 self joins towards the month number field to get what you need. If you only want a single filtered relationship at the time, then use a global number field for your key constant and a single self join.

Comment: Thank you both. I see the point. I followed Andreas' advice (I already had that month-number field). Now I get all the Jan records (in a new layout), which are usable, but also all the other records , only with empty fields. The aim is to import remotely only the records from 1 particular month, therefore I thought having the year split into 12 layouts by filtering the self-join I easily could import them month by month. What is the best way to get this?